# Array search in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have an array in javascript and a variable as follows:

```
var numArr = ["one", "two", "three"];
var searchNum = "four";
```

I want to search "four" in numArr and if not present then execute some statements... as in

```
if (searchNum not in numArr)
{
    // do this
}
```

Does javascript have any function which could search in any array and return true or false without me writing a whole lot of search code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if ( numArr.indexOf(searchNum) > -1 ) {

} else {}
```

The method will return -1 if it fails to find `searchNum`. Otherwise it will return the index at which it found it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
var result = [];
    for(i=0;i<listdata.names.length;i++){
        var n = listdata.names[i].toLocaleLowerCase();
        var s = x('input').value.toLocaleLowerCase();
        if(n.indexOf(s) != -1){result.push(listdata.names[i]);}
    }
```

This way we can output an result from an input value and existing array of values.

Little typicall to understand but..... :)